# Flattening nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, flatten

I'm trying to flatten a nested array but I'm getting undefined. I recently learnt `reduce` and am trying to apply the same logic.

```js
var list2 = [0, [1, [2, [3, [4, [5]]]]]];

function flat3(arr){
  arr.reduce(function(result, val, index){
    if(Array.isArray(val)){
      result = result.concat(val);
      flat3(val);
    } else {
      result.push(val);
    }
    return result;
  }, []);
}

console.log(flat3(list2));
```

I get undefined. Why? What am I missing?

Comment: why don't you just use this... https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: You're getting `undefined` because you're not returning `arr.reduce` for `flat3`

Comment: @A.Lau I don't want to use ES6's => instead i want to understand it in ES5 first. Can you please help me solve the problem?

Comment: I don't see why my post has got a -1 for asking a question (And even presenting my basic attempt)

Comment: Unfortunately, some people will dislike it even if they remotely think it's not worth answering

Comment: What is an associated array?

Comment: @torazaburo people can correct me if i'm wrong. Javascript does not inherently have associated array but it's prety much array inside array (deep nested array)

Comment: Then call it a deeply nested array.

Comment: I'll change the title. the reason why i called it associated array because it's a common terminology coming from other programming languages.

Comment: The term you were looking for was probably "associative array", but that means something different--it refers to an "array" whose elements are indexed by strings, usually, which is what in JS is called an "object".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning a value for `flat3`. This is what you're looking for:

```js
var list2 = [0, [1, [2, [3, [4, [5]]]]]];

function flat3(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(result, val, index) {
    if (Array.isArray(val)) {
      result = result.concat(flat3(val));
    } else {
      result.push(val);
    }
    return result;
  }, []);
}

console.log(flat3(list2));
```

Comment: It gives me the following: [ 0, 1, 2, [ 3, [ 4, [Object] ] ] ]

Comment: That code gives `[0,1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: I think i'm using an online editor, that's giving me issues. Thanks for the clarification!